# Spring integration, Setting error-handler on http outbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

If I add a custom error-handler to an int-http:outbound-gateway, the response body is not unmarshalled according to the expected-response-type, instead I only get a ResponseEntity returned. My custom error handler is pretty simple:

```
public class MyResponseErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlmaGetUserResponseErrorHandler.class);

@Override
public boolean hasError(final ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    // stop http 400 from returning true to error here.
    log.debug("Request has returned error code {}", response.getStatusCode());
    if (response.getBody() != null) {
        String returnBody = IOUtils.toString(response.getBody(), "UTF-8");
        log.debug("Checking error from response, code {}, body {}", response.getStatusCode(), returnBody);
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

As soon as I remove the error-handler, it unmarshalls the XML response into my POJO correctly.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I was streaming the body result out of the response for debug and hence the body was null.

Comment: Well, that's great you have found the solution yourself. So, feel free to delete the question or form the proper answer to gain some reputation

Answer (score 1):

The issue above was that the  MyResponseErrorHandler class was streaming out the body content before it was being passed to the marshaller for expected-response-type. Hence the body was null and a plain ResponseEntity was returned.